# Is there a way to cache Socket.IO responses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

For example, if I got this websocket:

```js
let itemsArray = [];

function fetchData() {
  itemsArray = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM Items`);
}

function emitData() {
  io.sockets.in("room_foo").emit("data", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
}

setInterval(() => fetchData(), 2500);
setInterval(() => emitData(), 5000);
```

*basically this means the following: stream to all clients in `room_foo` the JSON array every 5 seconds and fetch the data every 2,5 seconds*

Now, here's the problem. When I connect to that WebSocket I have to wait 5 seconds until the next emit event occurs.

**Is there a way I can cache the previous response for X *(5 in this specific case)* seconds, and emit that all the time in case someone connects, so they won't have such a delay?**
*Even if a new user connects (they don't have browser cache) - I mean server caching*

Comment: I don't know your structure but you can hold the data on global and send that?

Comment: @HalilÇakar I edit the post to make it a little more clear :-)

Comment: Oh yea maybe then just get ride of emitData and every time you get your data from `db.query` send it there. So it's gonna be updated everytime

Comment: @HalilÇakar Then the user still has to wait X amount of seconds, I would like it to be instant, like cache,,

Comment: @Nurfey, you can emit message on client connect. There you can send the message from a global variable. Overseeing something?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let itemsArray = [];

function fetchData() {
  itemsArray = await db.query(`SELECT * FROM Items`);
  io.sockets.in("room_foo").emit("data", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
}
setInterval(() => fetchData(), 2500);

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  // if user gets in to room_foo then send it so
  socket.join('room_foo', () => {
    io.sockets.in("room_foo").emit("data", JSON.stringify(itemsArray));
  })
});
```

So join taking a callback funciton use it :)

Maybe update your code like this?

Comment: I'll see what I can do with this, you will hear from me. Thank you in advance!